# Bounty information box needs some extra margin

Tags: bug, bounty, design

I noticed on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392769/activescaffold-thread-safety) question, that the "add a comment" option is partially on the bounty information box. In the `.question-status` style there is a `margin-bottom: -5px;`, if that was removed it would look a lot better.
[image]

It is showing like that for me on Chrome Version 37.0.2062.58 beta-m (64-bit) and FireFox 30.0

Comment: Ah, but it's not a duplicate. Your link is for "add comment" mine is for "add a comment". ;)

Comment: Why is it "add a comment" instead of "add comment" anyway??

Comment: The Overloads (Espheni), has commanded so? I think add a comment sounds better there.